# Change a style element across all components in Firemonkey

Tags: delphi, firemonkey, firemonkey-style

I am modifying the Dark Firemonkey style in XE6 which has a light orange glow around each component. I can individually change the color of the glow manually in each component type but its tedious as there are many different types of components, buttons, edit boxes etc.  Is there any way to change the color of the glow in all components simultaneously in the style editor (other than programmatically)?

I am using XE6. The screen shot below shows the glow around the memo box.

[image]

Comment: Almost as soon as I hit the return key I realized I could do a search and replace of the style file itself using a simple text editor. It worked. However, it would be interesting to know if the same operation can be done within the Delphi style editor.

Comment: No, it's not possible to do that in the Style Editor. I suggest you simply do it programmatically at runtime.